# Why am I unable to fully uninstall texlive in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: pdftex

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04. For a lot of reasons, I want to completely remove any LaTeX related before re-installing. I have followed the answers here step by step, but every time I type

```
pdflatex --version
```

The output I get is

```
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022)
kpathsea version 6.3.4
Copyright 2022 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.03
```

To be clear, I have tried all the combinations of "sudo apt remove" and "sudo apt remove --purge" etc and also removing the folders at /usr/local/texlive. Surely, I should have been able to uninstall texlive by doing this?

Comment: What's the output of `which pdflatex`? This should give you the information of where that executable is actually installed. Maybe this helps figuring out what package needs to be uninstalled in order to get rid of it

Comment: it looks like you are using texlive2022 installed from upstream from tug, not the Ubuntu system tex installed via apt.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered at my own expense that unfortunately there is more than one way to remove `LaTeX` from your distro.

As Raven suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/668978/why-am-i-unable-to-fully-uninstall-texlive-in-ubuntu-20-04#comment1662957_668978), It's possible that `pdflatex` is still in your PATH even if you tried to remove it.
So try to run the command `which pdflatex` first.
At this point, if you see that a path is returned, then the pdflatex executable is still in your computer.

What I did in the past was to remove it by modifying the shell's configuration file.

For example, if you are using the Bash shell, you can edit the `~/.bashrc` file and remove any lines that reference the pdflatex executable.
Once you've done that, you can check for aliases by running `alias pdflatex`.

If an alias is returned then you can remove it using `unalias pdflatex`.

Worst case scenario: the `pdflatex` command is being provided by another package that you have installed on your system. You have to figure out which is and then remove it.

Now you should be free to go

Comment: I'm not sure this is good advice. removing PATH settings from bashrc does not uninstall pdftex if it is installed (just stops you using it) and if pdftex is uninstalled, the PATH settings do no real harm and removing them does nothing other than cosmetc improvements to your environment. if `which pdflatex`  reports `/usr/bin` you are (most likely) using `apt-managed` tex, and you can uninstall via apt. If it reports `/usr/local/texlive/2022` you are using tex from TUG and you can uninstall by removing that directory.

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle I did indeed find /home/my_name/bin/pdflatex. I guess this is not where it should have been installed. The weird thing is that I cannot remove it using the "apt remove". Do I have to try auto remove and purge for example, or can I just remove the folder using "sudo rm -rf"?

Comment: apt will never touch files in your home directory.  is pdftex really in `~/bin` (that would be weird) or is that just a symbolic link to the installed location? @Abed

Comment: Yes, @DavidCarlisle I seem to have a bunch of latex related files in /home/my_name/bin. Would you recommend just removing these? I'm not sure how else to get rid of everything. FWIW, there was a probably a reason they were there: I was having trouble getting my latex to find some .sty files and I think I just installed everything in my home directory. That may have been a mistake.

Comment: I am not going to recommend removing anything you can't restore.  It's your machine you need to decide